# multiple GPUs keras weird speedup

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I did implement a similar code like the multi GPU code from keras 
([multiGPU tutorial](https://keras.io/utils/#multi_gpu_model)). When running this on a Server with 2 GPUs I have the following training times per epoch:

- showing Keras only one GPU and setting variable `gpus = 1` (only use one GPU), one epoch = 32s
- showing Keras two GPUs, and `gpus = 1`, one epoch = 31 s
- showing Keras two GPUs, and `gpus = 2`, one epoch = 37 s

the output looks a bit strange, while initializing the code seems to create multiple Tensorflow devices per GPU, I'm not sure if this is the correct behavior. But the most other examples I saw had just one such line per GPU.

first test (one GPU shown, gpus = 1):

```
2017-12-04 14:54:04.071549: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:955] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB
major: 6 minor: 0 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.3285
pciBusID 0000:82:00.0
Total memory: 15.93GiB
Free memory: 15.64GiB
2017-12-04 14:54:04.071597: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:976] DMA: 0 
2017-12-04 14:54:04.071605: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:986] 0:   Y 
2017-12-04 14:54:04.071619: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1045] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:82:00.0)
2017-12-04 14:54:21.531654: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1045] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:82:00.0)
```

second test (2 GPU shown, gpus = 1):

```
2017-12-04 14:48:24.881733: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:955] Found device 1 with properties: 
...(same as earlier)
2017-12-04 14:48:24.882924: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1045] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:82:00.0)
2017-12-04 14:48:24.882931: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1045] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:1) -> (device: 1, name: Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:83:00.0)
2017-12-04 14:48:42.353807: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1045] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:82:00.0)
2017-12-04 14:48:42.353851: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1045] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:1) -> (device: 1, name: Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:83:00.0)
```

and weirdly for example 3 (gpus = 2):

```
2017-12-04 14:41:35.906828: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:955] Found device 1 with properties:
...(same as earlier)
2017-12-04 14:41:35.907996: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1045] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:82:00.0)
2017-12-04 14:41:35.908002: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1045] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:1) -> (device: 1, name: Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:83:00.0)
2017-12-04 14:41:52.944335: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1045] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:82:00.0)
2017-12-04 14:41:52.944377: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1045] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:1) -> (device: 1, name: Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:83:00.0)
2017-12-04 14:41:53.709812: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1045] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:82:00.0)
2017-12-04 14:41:53.709838: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1045] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:1) -> (device: 1, name: Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:83:00.0)
```

the code:

```py
LSTM = keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM
model.add(LSTM(knots, input_shape=(timesteps, X_train.shape[-1]), return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(knots))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

if gpus>=2:
    model_basic = model
    with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
        model = model_basic
    parallel_model = multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=gpus)
    model = parallel_model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
hist = model.fit(myParameter)
```

Is this a typical behavior? What is wrong with my code that the multiple devices per GPU are created. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the exact code of [multiGPU tutorial](https://keras.io/utils/#multi_gpu_model).
It looks like its somehow the expected output. But to see the expected speed differences I had to increase the number of samples (20000) and needed to height and width to 100 (due to RAM limits).

I'm not completely sure why in my case I didn't see a speedup with two GPU. I expect it to be due to limits of the memory speed. Because my batch size is rather small and each sample is also small. This leads to the effect that the managing of the data needs more time than the actual calculation.
The distribution of the data gets even more time consuming when using 2 GPUs, while the actual runtime on each GPU decreases.
This effect could be proven if I could check the utilization of the graphics cards. Sadly I don't know how to do this.

If anyone has other ideas on this, let me know. Thanks

Comment: I'm facing the same issue! https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/9502